# mongodb flatten complex data for export

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to flatten my data model for export in a csv format.
I think I can get there with aggregation, but I don't know how,

the model consists of some arrays of objects, and I want to project
only certain fields of the objects along with other fields of the main object.

I have a model that looks like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId,
    "email" : string,
    "dates" : {
        "registered" : ISODate,
        "last_activity" : ISODate
    },
    "autos" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId,
            "make" : string,
            "model" : string,
            "color" : string
        }
    ],
    "boats": [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId,
            "manu" : string,
            "model" : string,
            "motor" : string
        }
    ]
}
```

This is as far as I've gotten with aggregation pipeline

```
db.users.aggregate( [ 
    { $unwind: "$autos" },
    {
      $project: {
          _id: 1,
          email: 1,
          'dates.registered': 1,
          'autos.make': 1,
          'autos.model': 1
      }
   }
 ] )
```

My return looks like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId(),
    "dates" : {
        "registered" : ISODate()
    },
    "email" : "...",
    "autos" : {
        "make" : "...",        
        "model" : "..."
    }
}
```

But I want my return to look like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId(),
    "registered" : ISODate(),
    "email" : "..."
    "auto_make" : "...",        
    "auto_model" : "..."
}
```

and as a follow up - is it possible to unwind a second array "boats"
in the same query????

So my results would look like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId(),
    "registered" : ISODate(),
    "email" : "...",       
    "auto_model" : "...",
    "auto_color" : "...",      
    "boat_model" : "...",    
    "boat_motor" : "...",
}
```

Comment: Does `autos` and `boats` always contain only single object inside it?

Comment: no - an array of objects

Comment: So which element do you want at the top from inside these arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the auto's make and model, you can do so easily by putting an `expression` into the value field inside `$project`'s key-value pair.

Regarding the boat's model and motor, you can redo what you have done to auto's to get the result

```
db.users.aggregate( [ 
    { $unwind: "$autos" }, //this line can be removed if you want the result to be an array instead of a string
    {
      $project: {
          _id: 1,
          email: 1,
          registered: '$dates.registered',
          auto_make: '$autos.make',
          auto_model: '$autos.model'
      }
   }
 ] )
```

```
output: (with unwind) 
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d15aa446810eb770fd47f7c"),
    "email" : "string",
    "registered" : ISODate("2019-06-28T05:48:52.652Z"),
    "auto_make" : "string",
    "auto_model" : "string"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d15aa446810eb770fd47f7c"),
    "email" : "string",
    "registered" : ISODate("2019-06-28T05:48:52.652Z"),
    "auto_make" : "string",
    "auto_model" : "string"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d15aa446810eb770fd47f7c"),
    "email" : "string",
    "registered" : ISODate("2019-06-28T05:48:52.652Z"),
    "auto_make" : "string",
    "auto_model" : "string"
}
```

```
output: (without unwind))
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d15aa446810eb770fd47f7c"),
    "email" : "string",
    "registered" : ISODate("2019-06-28T05:48:52.652Z"),
    "auto_make" : [ 
        "string", 
        "string", 
        "string"
    ],
    "auto_model" : [ 
        "string", 
        "string", 
        "string"
    ]
}
```

**Updated: unwinding both**

This example gives 6 output documents for 1 user with 2 auto, 3 boats

```
db.temp.aggregate( [ 
    { $unwind: "$autos" }, 
    { $unwind: "$boats" }, 
    {
      $project: {
          _id: 1,
          email: 1,
          registered: '$dates.registered',
          auto_make: '$autos.make',
          auto_model: '$autos.model',
          boat_model: '$boats.model',
          boat_motor: '$boats.motor'
      }
   }
 ] )
```

Comment: thx Andy - but how would I get the boats in the same result - isn't that a second unwind? where does it go, before or after the project?

Comment: Do you prefer to have the `unwinded` or `not-unwinded` version?

Comment: unwind would be pref

Comment: I think the `unwind` version does not make much sense. A user can have multiple autos and boats. Say 2 auto and 3 boats. If you `unwind` it, you may end up with 3 document. First and second with 1 auto and boat. The third with only a boat. It seems a bit strange.

Comment: Or, another way of unwinding would output a combination of 2 auto and 3 boats.
{auto1, boat1}
{auto1, boat2}
... {auto2, boat3}

Comment: yes - it is a bit strange...but think of a spreadsheet representing the data - i realize there will be rows with autos and no boats and etc,..

Comment: I think it mostly depends on your purpose. Say, if you want to study the relationship between auto-to-boat purchase, it makes sense to use `Approach #2` to output all the combinations, even though the number of output documents are way more.

Comment: I need the flat data for statistical analysis, it doesn't all have to be on one result, I can run one query for autos, and one query for boats...I just thought it might be quicker and easier for the person running the analysis to run this query once for all the data - then they could chop and dice the csv file as they wish...

Comment: there are actually a dozen different arrays, not just autos and boats... so running 12 queries seemed like a lot to put on the analyst, but you are correct - it is clearer and less confusing keeping it separate.

Comment: however I am still curious how to unwind more than once - there are a few examples that said I had to double unwind objects - but your example was much cleaner and made more sense.

Comment: @jpmyob I am glad that helps. Operations in aggregation are performed sequentially. Having 2 unwind simply means that you unwind one array and produce more number of documents. Unwind another array on the new document set. I updated the code above on the answer.